# Как посчитать процентное соотношение единичных покупателей относительно вернувшихся?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица заказов `orders`:

```
Name        Type
id          int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
email       varchar(100) NULL
dateCreated timestamp NULL
```

Примерные данные:

```
    id  email                     dateCreated          
------  ------------------------  ---------------------
 18279  salsita@XXX.vom           2016-01-20 18:19:37  
 18278  Clayton_M@XXX.net         2016-01-20 18:05:49  
 18276  elliot.flaig@XXX.com      2016-01-20 17:45:48  
 18275  jlmasaro@XXX.ru           2016-01-20 17:41:53  
 18273  dellat2007@XXX.com        2016-01-20 17:30:18  
 18270  kamran_farooq2002@XXX.su  2016-01-20 17:15:11  
 18266  jordanblanchard@XXX.com   2016-01-20 17:04:26  
 18265  jlmasaro@XXX.ru           2015-12-25 17:00:37  
 18264  majidalhareri@XXX.com     2015-12-20 16:57:08  
 18262  jlmasaro@XXX.ru           2015-11-12 16:50:36
```

Задача: посчитать процентное соотношение единичных покупателей против тех, кто уже покупал, за какой-либо временной отрезок.

Т.е. ожидается получить что-то типа

```
Date range  New  Returning
----------  ---  ---------
Dec 2015    5    7
Nov 2015    8    8
Oct 2015    6    8
```

Главная проблема для меня это как определить, что покупатель новый / единичный в определенный момент времени.
Т.е. скажем есть 5 заказов с одного email адреса. Первый заказ - он единичный покупатель. А остальные 4 заказа этот же email адрес должен рассматриваться как вернувшийся :(

Например, в примере выше email `jlmasaro@XXX.ru` в ноябре должен считаться как новичок, а в декабре и январе - как вернувшийся клиент...

Видимо надо для каждого заказа каждого email адреса получить порядковый номер заказа. Те, у которых номер 1, первые, единичные (на тот момент)... Остальные заказы этого клиента - возврат. Наверное так.
Но как это сделать?

Любые идеи приветствуются...

Comment: Не могли бы проделать ручной подсчёт ожидаемых результатов для приведённого примера? Чтобы точно понять, что нужно получить в итоге.

Comment: данные были даны просто для примера. Они не существенны. Поменял на структуру и добавил пример ожидаемого ответа

Comment: Нет, почему вы удалили примерную таблицу? Она мне помогала понять яснее. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример таблицы и подсчёта.

Comment: изменено. Ну и я добавил один адрес в пример, которые, по его временному разбросу, и дает мне проблемы...

Comment: Спасибо, теперь задача ясна.

Comment: А если одна и та же почта в одном месяца появилась дважды?

Comment: Такое безумие: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/632463/13 , предполагается, что нет двух заказов с одного ящика, с одинаковой датой.

Comment: @zRrr можете оформить свой комментарий, как ответ?

Comment: @cyadvert примите тот ответ, что есть. А сколько записей в таблице, на которой такое не тормозит?

Comment: @zRrr пока все 50 000. Но растет очень быстро...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условия "новый клиент" и "повторный клиент" можно выразить внутри агрегатной функции, сравнивая дату заказа и **дату первого заказа клиента** и выдавая пусто или непусто.
То же самое можно выразить через LEFT JOIN, но мне кажется вот так нагляднее:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(o.`order_date`, '%Y-%m') AS `month`,
  COUNT(*) AS `cnt`,
  SUM(IF(o.`order_date`=c.`first_time`,1,NULL)) AS `new_cnt`,
  SUM(IF(o.`order_date`=c.`first_time`,NULL,1)) AS `ret_cnt`
FROM
  `orders` AS o JOIN
  `clients` AS c ON o.`email`=c.`email`
GROUP BY `month`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76fda/2

**Замечение**:
В своём примере я оформил `clients` как вьюшку от таблицы `orders`. На практике, конечно же, удобнее добавить поля `first_time` и `cnt` в *таблицу* "клиенты".

Comment: да, ответ хороший. Подходит. Однако создавать отдельный view под это дело мне не подходит. Этот view как подзапрос в join вставлю. Однако такой вариант уже предложил @zRrr. Если он не оформит свой комментарий как ответ - приму Ваш. Подождем немного.

Comment: @cyadvert Как вариант: `SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(o.order_date, '%Y-%m') AS month,
  COUNT(c.email) as new_cnt,
  COUNT(o.email)-COUNT(c.email) AS old_cnt
    FROM
  orders AS o LEFT JOIN
   (
     SELECT email,MIN(order_date) AS first_time
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY email
   ) as c
  ON o.email=c.email and o.order_date=c.first_time
GROUP BY month`

Comment: @cyadvert как я писал, вьюшка это не рекомендуемое мной решение. Я советую использовать "статические" данные из таблицы вместо вычисления всякий раз.

Comment: Т.е. Вы считаете, что имеет смысл создать отдельную колонку под номер заказа? Надо ли? Ради одного запроса создавать и поддерживать его...?

Comment: @cyadvert От частоты использования запроса зависит. Это же аналитика, она небось нужна каким нибудь манагерам пару раз в месяц, тогда поддерживать отдельную колонку конечно не интересно. Если вы это вдруг показываете каждому вошедшему на сайт - тогда конечно надо кешировать результат. И кстати, если у вас запрос _всегда_ будет без ограничений по периоду дат, т.е. вся таблица целиком - можно за один проход по таблице сделать, могу расписать.

Comment: @Mike да не, спасибо. Я уже все сделал. С правильно расставленными индексами все нипочем :) Запрос будет запускаться не чаще раза в месяц, так что не стану я отдельную колонку создавать. Надо им - пусть ждут :)

Comment: @cyadvert я где-то упоминал номер заказа? Цитирую себя: «удобнее добавить поля first_time и cnt в таблицу "клиенты"». То есть, когда клиент впервые купил, сохраняем дату clients.first_time. При каждой покупке +1 к clients.cnt. В любой момент у нас есть статистика для каждого клиента без тяжелых запросов. Без вьюшек.

Comment: под "номером заказа" я имел ввиду порядковый номер заказа этого клиента. Я не так выразился - сорри... В принципе Ваша мысль понятна, и я с ней полность согласен. Однако в моем конкретном случае я все же решил не добавлять лишний полей в таблицу. Если запросы станут напряжными - добавлю. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь. Плюсик я уже поставил Вашему ответу.